# Nmap Script ssl-dh-params tls.lua Error On Execution

Tags: centos7, nmap

I am using Nmap to verify some of our servers settings to make sure we are compliant. One of the things that popped up in a scan, but had not been in any of the other previous scans was an issue with our key exchange size. We were allowing 1028 and to be compliant it needs to be limited to 2048.

So I wanted to make this change and be able to validate that change I was hoping to use the Nmap script 'ssl-dh-params'.

This script did not come with the default install from the yum repository that we are using. So I went to the nmap site and downloaded what I believe to be all of the missing .nse & .lua files.

I have hit a wall where it does not appear that I need any additional libraries. When I run either  of the following commands:

```
>nmap --script ssl-dh-params endpoint-to-be-tested.com
```

```
>nmap --script-updatedb
```

I get the same error regarding the tls.lua file:

```
Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2022-08-02 15:06 EDT
NSE: Failed to load /usr/bin/../share/nmap/scripts/ssl-dh-params.nse:
/usr/bin/../share/nmap/nselib/tls.lua:340: attempt to call upvalue 'pack' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
        /usr/bin/../share/nmap/nselib/tls.lua:340: in function 'signature_algorithms'
        /usr/bin/../share/nmap/nselib/tls.lua:1643: in main chunk
        [C]: in function 'require'
        /usr/bin/../share/nmap/scripts/ssl-dh-params.nse:8: in function </usr/bin/../share/nmap/scripts/ssl-dh-params.nse:1>
NSE: failed to initialize the script engine:
/usr/bin/../share/nmap/nse_main.lua:547: could not load script
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'error'
        /usr/bin/../share/nmap/nse_main.lua:547: in function 'new'
        /usr/bin/../share/nmap/nse_main.lua:783: in function 'get_chosen_scripts'
        /usr/bin/../share/nmap/nse_main.lua:1271: in main chunk
        [C]: in ?

QUITTING!
```

I am not sure what my next steps are for ironing this out. Below is a list of the libraries I have installed in the '/usr/share/nmap/nselib/' directory:

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  71K Aug  8  2019 afp.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  16K Aug  8  2019 ajp.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  13K Aug  8  2019 amqp.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  13K Aug  8  2019 asn1.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 5.3K Aug  8  2019 base32.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 4.5K Aug  8  2019 base64.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  18K Aug  8  2019 bitcoin.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  40K Aug  8  2019 bittorrent.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 8.9K Aug  8  2019 bjnp.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  33K Aug  8  2019 brute.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 6.5K Aug  8  2019 cassandra.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  17K Aug  8  2019 citrixxml.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 8.8K Aug  8  2019 comm.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  15K Aug  8  2019 creds.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 3.1K Aug  8  2019 cvs.lua
drwxr-xr-x. 4 root root 4.0K Jun 30 11:50 data
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  12K Aug  8  2019 datafiles.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  19K Aug  8  2019 dhcp6.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  30K Aug  8  2019 dhcp.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  21K Aug  8  2019 dnsbl.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  53K Aug  8  2019 dns.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  13K Aug  8  2019 dnssd.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  24K Aug  8  2019 drda.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 7.9K Aug  8  2019 eap.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  14K Aug  8  2019 eigrp.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 2.1K Aug  8  2019 ftp.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  21K Aug  8  2019 giop.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 3.0K Aug  8  2019 gps.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  95K Aug  8  2019 http.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  29K Aug  8  2019 httpspider.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 9.1K Aug  8  2019 iax2.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  15K Aug  8  2019 ike.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 9.3K Aug  8  2019 imap.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  40K Aug  8  2019 informix.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  20K Aug  8  2019 ipOps.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  12K Aug  8  2019 ipp.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  23K Aug  8  2019 iscsi.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  15K Aug  8  2019 isns.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  44K Aug  8  2019 jdwp.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  15K Aug  8  2019 json.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  26K Aug  8  2019 ldap.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 4.7K Aug  8  2019 listop.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 2.0K Aug  8  2019 match.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 9.1K Aug  8  2019 membase.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 8.2K Aug  8  2019 mobileme.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  23K Aug  8  2019 mongodb.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 181K Aug  8  2019 msrpc.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  29K Aug  8  2019 msrpcperformance.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 175K Aug  8  2019 msrpctypes.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 107K Aug  8  2019 mssql.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  17K Aug  8  2019 mysql.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 4.8K Aug  8  2019 natpmp.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  37K Aug  8  2019 ncp.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  11K Aug  8  2019 ndmp.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  14K Aug  8  2019 netbios.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 6.1K Aug  8  2019 nrpc.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 3.4K Aug  8  2019 nsedebug.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 4.8K Aug  8  2019 omp2.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 7.7K Aug  8  2019 ospf.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  41K Aug  8  2019 packet.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  20K Aug  8  2019 pgsql.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 5.9K Aug  8  2019 pop3.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  29K Aug  8  2019 pppoe.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  12K Aug  8  2019 proxy.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 2.8K Aug  2 14:54 rand.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  11K Aug  8  2019 rdp.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 3.2K Aug  8  2019 redis.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  47K Aug  8  2019 rmi.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  11K Aug  8  2019 rpcap.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 111K Aug  8  2019 rpc.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 4.9K Aug  8  2019 rsync.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 8.5K Aug  8  2019 rtsp.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  16K Aug  8  2019 sasl.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 7.3K Aug  8  2019 shortport.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  28K Aug  8  2019 sip.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  33K Aug  8  2019 smbauth.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 163K Aug  8  2019 smb.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  21K Aug  8  2019 smtp.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  14K Aug  8  2019 snmp.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 9.7K Aug  8  2019 socks.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  12K Aug  8  2019 srvloc.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 7.2K Aug  8  2019 ssh1.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 9.0K Aug  8  2019 ssh2.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 9.5K Aug  8  2019 sslcert.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  39K Aug  8  2019 stdnse.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 4.6K Aug  8  2019 strbuf.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 2.6K Aug  8  2019 strict.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 4.4K Aug  2 14:52 stringaux.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  11K Aug  8  2019 stun.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 2.1K Aug  2 14:53 tableaux.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 3.3K Aug  8  2019 tab.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 4.0K Aug  8  2019 target.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 9.1K Aug  8  2019 tftp.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  70K Aug  2 14:49 tls.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  62K Aug  8  2019 tns.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 9.8K Aug  8  2019 unpwdb.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  11K Aug  8  2019 upnp.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  12K Aug  8  2019 url.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 8.5K Aug  8  2019 versant.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 8.3K Aug  8  2019 vnc.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  75K Aug  8  2019 vulns.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  16K Aug  8  2019 vuzedht.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  12K Aug  8  2019 wsdd.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  12K Aug  8  2019 xdmcp.lua
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root  15K Aug  8  2019 xmpp.lua
```

OS: CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)

Nmap Version output:

```
Nmap version 6.40 ( http://nmap.org )
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
Compiled with: nmap-liblua-5.2.2 openssl-1.0.2k libpcre-8.32 libpcap-1.5.3 nmap-libdnet-1.12 ipv6
Compiled without:
Available nsock engines: epoll poll select
```

Is there something I am missing that needs to be installed to get the 'ssl-dh-params' script to run?

Or is this as basic as I am missing some parameters?

Thank you
James Anderson

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out what the issue was. In this scenario I installed Nmap from the yum repository available. The version installed from the repo was v6.40. To be able to utilize the 'ssl-dh-params' script from nmap you need to be on a greater version regardless of the packages installed.

Nmap provided great instructions on installing using RPM and their current package list. [link]https://nmap.org/book/inst-linux.html#inst-rpm

To resolve I uninstalled the current installation of Nmap using `yum remove nmap` and then installed using RPM instructions from Nmap's site listed above.